# optimize projection of item count of entity into a view model

Tags: sql, performance, linq, entity-framework, iqueryable

I use ASP.NET MVC 5 with EF 6, code first approach. I have entities A and B, where A has a collection of Bs.

I want to produce a a bunch of view models that looks like this:

```
class ViewModelForA{
    public int SomePropertyOfA {get;set};
    public int BCount {get;set;}
}
```

the query looks like this:

```
dbCtx.A.Select(x=> 
   new ViewModelForA {
       SomePropertyOfA = x.Prop,
       BCount = x.Bs.Count()   //problem
   });
```

using MiniProfiler [miniprofiler](http://miniprofiler.com/) I see that a unique sql select statement is generated for each 
count of Bs. Assume I have 100s of Bs in an A, this becomes slow.

this is the SQL generated from `x.Bs.Count()`:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
'more columns, omitted sql
FROM [dbo].[B] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[AId] = @EntityKeyValue1
```

and i thought I would get something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM [dbo].[B] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[AId] = @EntityKeyValue1
```

This is not a question of caching the count value, but to optimize the creation of the viewmodels with as few sql selects generated as possible. 
BTW, I don't want to use eager loading, because A and B ( in the real code) are pretty heavyweight.

How can I do this?

Comment: How would you write this query in SQL? Without a predicate, you are always going to be doing a full scan of A and B so I'm not sure what type of performance increase you are looking for. What does the query plan look like for this query?

Comment: What version of Entity Framework are you using? (I just tested this scenario with EF 5 and it generated efficient SQL.)

Comment: @SteveRuble can you please show the efficient sql generated?

Comment: `SELECT 
[Extent1].[RedactedPK] AS [RedactedPK], 
[Extent1].[DataFoundMessage] AS [DataFoundMessage], 
(SELECT 
 COUNT(1) AS [A1]
 FROM [dbo].[RedactedDriver] AS [Extent2]
 WHERE [Extent1].[RedactedPK] = [Extent2].[RedactedFK]) AS [C1]
FROM [dbo].[Redacted] AS [Extent1]`

Comment: @SteveRuble hmmm interesting. I use ef6

Comment: hey @Balanikas i'm facing this same issue. even if i use .Include() on the child property to add a join it is not firing a count(*) in sql! I'm using EF6 too.